# Jenkins reporting build as unstable/failed as it is unable to publish test result report

Tags: jenkins

[image]We have configured Jenkins jobs to run our Automated TCs.
Intermittently I am getting the build being unstable/failed with error

Test report file c:\automation\test\JUnit\trunk\sbpm\SBPMTestProject\src\reportsJunit\Web\TEST-com.softwareag.sbpm.web.testSuites.BC_UI_BVTBETA_TestSuite.xml was length 0

Wonder what is causing for this error to be reported?
Is it because of the time out limit or is there any max size that has been overshoot?
Attached is the screenshot to report the Junits execution into the xaml file and its location.

Comment: You need to dig in further and figure out why you're producing a 0 sized xml file for your test suites.

Comment: Hi, 
Jenkins itself will create the xml file for the execution status. How would we have control over the size of the file?

Comment: your job run tests and creates xml with results, jenkins trying to read it, but file is empty.

Comment: Jenkins will actually write the file after the execution and not read it.

Comment: This is generally due to the test framework you are using not producing the output. Is it in the wrong place? Keep the workspace and check it out. What's the console logs say? Are you getting output from your tests there?